# Can't load a template in Django - 'TemplateDoesNotExist at /home/' error

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django from 'Mastering Django: Core' book and now I'm
stucked in this third chapter of the book which describes about the Django template.
The problem I'm facing is I can't load a template from a specific directory because it gives me this "TemplateDoesNotExist at /home/" error.

Here is my project directory :

```
mywebsite/
    mywebapp/
        ...
        ...
        views.py
        ...
    temp/
        template.html
```

Here is `TEMPLATES` list from `settings.py` :

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['/home/temp'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And finally here's my view :

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
    def home(request):
        t = get_template("template.html")
        c = Context({'heading':'Welcome to MyWebsite.',
                    'name':'Arya Stark','age':19})
        return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Note: The template I'm using in this view is in the `temp` directory.
So, can you please explain me why would that error happen?

Comment: remove /home from template dirs  and check. only keep /temp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set `DIRS` to "/home/temp", but as you've clearly shown in your directory structure, your templates are in "mywebsite/temp". You'll probably need to use the full path there, or at least `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'temp')`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if in your settings.py BASE_DIR is declared, if it is,

then check,

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Also, in your DIRS in TEMPLATES,

```
'DIRS' : [BASE_DIR + '/temp/',]
```

This should do the trick,

Also, django as default checks for the sub-directory templates in your app-directory and project-directory as well, when you APP_DIRS = True.